# React document.createRange is not a function

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I'm using Enzyme with Jest in Create-react-app application.

Current behavior
I have a test which uses the mount method for a React component to find an element on a page. The test passes but a warning gets printed out:

(node:79591) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: document.createRange is not a function

The test in question:

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";
import UnitGroup from './UnitGroup';
import { UnitGroupHeading } from '../UnitGroupHeading/UnitGroupHeading';

it('should render properly', () => {
   shallow(<UnitGroup />);
});

it('should render UnitGroupHeading properly', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<UnitGroup unit={{name: 'test'}} />);
  expect(wrapper.find(UnitGroupHeading)).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

Comment: Your first test doesn't test anything.  `shallow` should be used to setup your component for subsequent testing.  Do you really need `mount` in your test?  What happens if you shallow render it instead?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jest/Enzyme document.createRange is not a function on mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51887552/jest-enzyme-document-createrange-is-not-a-function-on-mount)