# Jest/Enzyme document.createRange is not a function on mount

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, enzyme

When trying to use ezymes `mount` on a component that is rendering MaterialUI's Tooltip, there is an error stopping my tests:

`TypeError: document.createRange is not a function`

Answer (score 13):

To fix this I defined `document.createRange` in my `./src/setupTest.js`

```
  document.createRange = () => ({
    setStart: () => {},
    setEnd: () => {},
    commonAncestorContainer: {
      nodeName: "BODY",
      ownerDocument: document,
    },
  })
```

Comment: I am using this solution. But i am getting typescript error. Can you resolve this issue.(property) Range.commonAncestorContainer: Node
Returns the node, furthest away from the document, that is an ancestor of both range's start node and end node.
Error : 
Type '{ nodeName: string; ownerDocument: Document; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Node': baseURI, childNodes, firstChild, isConnected, and 45

Answer (score 5):

For anyone looking Typescript solution

```
  document.createRange = () => ({
    setStart: jest.fn(),
    setEnd: jest.fn(),
    // @ts-ignore
    commonAncestorContainer: {
      nodeName: 'BODY',
      ownerDocument: document,
    },
  })
```